# Access elements of Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
const guests = [
               { id: 1, rsvp: true },
               { id: 2, rsvp: false },
               { id: 3, rsvp: true  },
               { id: 4, rsvp: false }
             ];
```

I would like to write a function which selects only the objects corresponding to IDs (guests) who have rsvp'd.

```
function selectGuests(guests, id) {
  list.forEach(function(id) {
    if(id.true) {
      push.SelectGuests();
    }
});

  return selectGuests;
}
```

however, I am getting gibberish results.

Any help on this one or points in the right direction would be appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simplified version without using es6 features.

```
function selectGuests(guests) {
  var selectedGuests = []
  // forEach gets the array elements (one by one) as first param 
  guests.forEach(function(guest) {
    if(guest.rsvp) {
      selectedGuests.push(guest)
    }
  })
  return selectedGuests
}

// call it as follows 
selectGuests(guests)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**DEMO**

```js
 const guests = [
               { id: 1, rsvp: true },
               { id: 2, rsvp: false },
               { id: 3, rsvp: true  },
               { id: 4, rsvp: false }
];

var result = guests.filter(t=>t.rsvp);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

using `forEach`

```js
function selectGuests(guests) 
{
    let result = [];
    guests.forEach(function (guest) {
        if (guest.rsvp) {
            result.push(guest);
        }
    });

    return result;
}

const guests = [
    { id: 1, rsvp: true },
    { id: 2, rsvp: false },
    { id: 3, rsvp: true  },
    { id: 4, rsvp: false }
];

let a = selectGuests(guests);
console.log(a);
```

or simpler using `filter` method

```js
const guests = [
    { id: 1, rsvp: true },
    { id: 2, rsvp: false },
    { id: 3, rsvp: true  },
    { id: 4, rsvp: false }
];

let a = guests.filter(function(item){return item.rsvp});
console.log(a);
```